# Extracting text between tags using a particular word

Tags: html, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract text between tags of a HTML page using a keyword. Here is an example.

```
<div class="xyz">Title</div>
<h4>Education</h4>
<p>PhD, 2017, Subject,<br />
   ABC University </p>
```

I'm want to fetch `"PhD, 2017, Subject, ABC University"`. Here is what I tried:

```
r = requests.get(site)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
for elems in soup(text=re.compile('PhD')):
    val = elems.find_parent('p').getText()
```

This is printing all the 'p' tags containing "PhD", can someone suggest how do I get the specific data under "Education" field? I tried using partition too, which didn't provide successful outcome.

Comment: Do you want to get all words or only some words from whole code?

Comment: The html contains information about the education of a person. I want to scrape only those details. So some words from the code and all the words that come under the education or degrees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use [`lxml.html`](http://lxml.de/installation.html) to get desired text:

```
import lxml.html as html

source = requests.get(site).content
html_obj = html.fromstring(source)
my_text = " ".join([text.strip() for text in html_obj.xpath('//h4[.="Education"]/following-sibling::p/text()')])
print(my_text)
```

*Output*

```
'PhD, 2017, Subject, ABC University'
```

Comment: It works. Thank you. I just have another query, since each page is unique, in case I come across a h2 or other tag containing the required information, can I get it using an or condition in .xpath?

Comment: You can specify `*` which will match *any* parent tag- `//*[.="Education"]/following-sibling::p/text()` or something like `//*[(self::h4 or self::h2) and .="Education"]/following-sibling::p/text()` to match both `h4` or/and `h2` parent

Comment: Alright! so, the same applies to the education too? or should I use regex?

Comment: Yes. Text node can also be different

Comment: While scarping I came across this particular html 
`<h2 class='field-label'>Education</h2>            
 <div class="field field-name-field-faculty-education field-type-text-long field-label-hidden field-wrapper">
  <div class="field-items" class="field-items">
   <div class="field-item odd" class="field-item even">
            <ul>
            <li>PhD ABC University</li>
            </ul>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>`
I tried using `//*[.="Education"]/following-sibling::div[@class="field-items"]/text()`
Is there something wrong with the xpath I chose?

Comment: Yep. `div[@class="field-item‌​s"]` is not a sibling of `h2`, but child of sibling `div`. Also note that `div/text()` means text node that is **instant** child of `div`. You need something like `//*[.="Education"]/following::div[@class="field-items"]//text()`

Comment: I optimized using `//*[.="Education"]/following::li[1]/text()`. Thank you, Xpath did come in handy.

Answer (score 1):

With BeautifulSoup you can:

```
import bs4 as bs
text = """<div class="xyz">Title</div>
    <h4>Not Education</h4>
    <p>PhD, 2016, Subject,<br />
     DEF University </p>
    <div class="xyz">Title</div>
    <h4>Education</h4>
    <p>PhD, 2017, Subject,<br />
     ABC University </p>"""

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(text, "lxml")
header = soup.find('h4', text='Education')
val = header.find_next_sibling('p').getText()
print (val)
```

outputs:

```
PhD, 2017, Subject,
     ABC University
```